# csv php indexing not working

Tags: php, csv

I have one csv file "food.csv" and details are in the following order.  Total rows are 10 and columns 5. And i wnat the file to be indexed by php to get the array of "Mango".

```
ITEM,DESC,QTY,RATE,TYPE
124,APPLE,20,300,NEW
123,MANGO,10,500,NEW
135,BANANA,30,600,OLD
148,ORANGE,12,40,NEW
111,MANGO,20,150,OLD
125,APPLE,7,100,OLD
```

Following is the PHP code but it is not working.

```
<?php
$eurl = "http://www.xyz.com/food.csv";
if (($handle = fopen ( $eurl, "r" )) !== FALSE) {
    $keys = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, ";" );
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, ";" )) !== FALSE ) {
if ($r2->id == "MANGO") {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }

        $res[] = array_combine($keys, $data);
    }
    fclose ($handle);
}
var_dump($res);
?>
```

I require the result in following manner. Can anybody help me in correcting the code?

When the index key is "MANGO", it should give the output as:

MANGO    10 Kgs @ 500USD (123-NEW)

MANGO    20 Kgs @ 150USD (111 -OLD)

Comment: Change if ($r2->id == "MANGO")  to if ($data[1] == "MANGO")

Comment: Also change parameter 3 of your fgetcsv from `";"` to `","` as your field seperator is a comma and not a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also when you cannot visualize the array that is being produced, and it is an array and not an object add some debug code like so

```
<?php
    $eurl = "http://www.xyz.com/food.csv";
    if (($handle = fopen ( $eurl, "r" )) !== FALSE) {
        $keys = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, "," );

        $output = '';

        while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, "," )) !== FALSE ) {
            var_dump( $data );
            if ($data[1] == "MANGO") {
                $found = true;

                $output .= sprintf( "%s %d Kgs @ %dUSD (%d-%s)\n", 
                                   $data[1],
                                   $data[2],
                                   $data[3],
                                   $data[0],
                                   $data[4]
                                 );
            }
            // this makes no sense here, but I dont know what you were trying to do at this point
            $res[] = array_combine($keys, $data);
        }
        fclose ($handle);
    }

    echo $output;

    var_dump($res);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen("$link_file","r")or die("file dont exist");
$output = '';
while (!feof($handle )){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle,4096,",");
        if($data[1] =="MANGO"){
          $output .= sprintf( "%s %d Kgs @ %dUSD (%d-%s)<br>", 
                                       $data[1],
                                       $data[2],
                                       $data[3],
                                       $data[0],
                                       $data[4]
                                       );
        }

}
echo $output;
fclose($handle);
```

this will echo:

```
MANGO 10 Kgs @ 500USD (123-NEW)
MANGO 20 Kgs @ 150USD (111-OLD)
```